# Create installer for WindowsApplication C#

Tags: c#, windows

I try to create an installer for my WindowsApplication. I use the Publish and it work.

I use Visual Studio 2019 and .NET Framework 4.7.2.

[image]

The problem is when i run the installer the application also run.

I want (if possible) avoid this behavior..I want to run only the installer not also the application after install.

there is some settings to define?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably detail what settings and options you used during the Publish process. Also, what (desktop) framework is this? The publish process may vary greatly between ex. winforms, WPF, MAUI, etc

Comment: There are several technologies available for creating installers.  Which one are you using?  Is there any relevant code you can show us?

Comment: I use visual studio and .NET Fram. 4.7.2 for my Windows Application.. In the properties project i only run the Publish option..sorry is the first time

Comment: Wix is a good tool: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/intro/

Comment: There is an option in VS, go to solution explorer, right click project, then click publish then there should be an option "Start application after installation".. you need to uncheck it. Sorry I’m not in froyof PC. But it should be like this only @DevOps85

Comment: @viveknuna i try but i'm not have this option..